# Where does Windows store the secring?

Tags: windows, gnupg, pgp

I can't find where GnuPG located my `secring` *(actually, I can't find any `gpg` files, only`kbx` files)*, as all I have in `%AppData%\gnupg` is:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: When listing tree information, it's more efficient to list it within a code box _(cmd: `dir`, powershell: `ls`)_

Answer (score 0):

There hasn't been a 'secring' since 2014. GnuPG 2.1 and later versions use a different storage format – the old .pgp/.gpg file format was replaced with a .kbx "keybox" format for faster access (although pubring.gpg is still recognized), and secret key handling was moved out of gpg itself into gpg-agent.

Instead of duplicating whole keyblocks between "pubring" and "secring" (like previous PGP and GnuPG versions), all private keys are stored in the **`private-keys-v1.d`** directory, in a different format without any PGP-specific metadata.

(This location is shared between PGP private keys in *gpg*, S/MIME private keys in *gpgsm*, and SSH private keys in the SSH Agent mode of *gpg-agent*.)

Use `gpg -K --with-keygrip` to determine the file name used for each private key (this is *not* the same as the PGP fingerprint), and note that each subkey's private part is stored in a separate file – if you have a key with 3 subkeys, then you'll have 4 `.key` files (which in theory could even have different passwords).